# C# async/await flow misunderstanding

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm writing a service that charts some data. The data is retrieved from blob storage by a client that only has an `async` `Get` method to get the data. Once the data is retrieved it is used to populate the chart and this is done using another method `Redraw` that is also `async`. I would like the chart to update every minute or so so I have the `Get` and `Redraw` called inside a while loop with a delay.

```
private async Task Redraw(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var data = await DataProvider.Get();

        await Chart.Redraw(data.Labels, new[] {data.DataSet});

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails. I get a `NullReferenceException` and a `AggregateException` from somewhere in the chart library. Modifying the code as follows does work.

```
private async Task Redraw(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var data = Task.Run(() => DataProvider.Get()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        await Task.WhenAll(Chart.Redraw(data.Labels, new[] {data.DataSet}));

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the first version using async/await fails. I believe that it's because the `Redraw` is trying to run before the data task is finished but I also believed that awaiting the `Get` method would mean that `Redraw` would not be called until the data task was complete. When I debug those lines the data does appear to be populated before the next line is executed so i'm a bit confused.

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in
>   Blazorise.Charts.dll Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   in System.Private.CoreLib.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost):
>   Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'.
>   'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.1\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer:
>   Warning: Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at Blazorise.Charts.JS.ToChartDataSet[T](ChartData`1
>   data)    at
>   Blazorise.Charts.JS.InitializeChart[TItem,TOptions](IJSRuntime
>   runtime, DotNetObjectReference`1 dotNetObjectReference, Boolean
>   hasClickEvent, Boolean hasHoverEvent, String canvasId, ChartType type,
>   ChartData`1 data, TOptions options, String dataJsonString, String
>   optionsJsonString)    at Blazorise.Charts.BaseChart`4.Initialize()
>   at Blazorise.Charts.BaseChart`4.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean
>   firstRender)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost: Error:
>   Unhandled exception in circuit
>   'v_kcV7GT8jgmXOLCuNjM_i918pfAqsaPh5KVrAsZNUw'.
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.)  --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at Blazorise.Charts.JS.ToChartDataSet[T](ChartData`1
>   data)    at
>   Blazorise.Charts.JS.InitializeChart[TItem,TOptions](IJSRuntime
>   runtime, DotNetObjectReference`1 dotNetObjectReference, Boolean
>   hasClickEvent, Boolean hasHoverEvent, String canvasId, ChartType type,
>   ChartData`1 data, TOptions options, String dataJsonString, String
>   optionsJsonString)    at Blazorise.Charts.BaseChart`4.Initialize()
>   at Blazorise.Charts.BaseChart`4.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean
>   firstRender)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I'm digging deeper and I don't think the null reference is being throw when calling `Chart.Redraw` at all. When this line executes the data is not null. Instead it looks like it is related somehow to async/await. The call that precedes `Redraw` looks like this..

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!_isAlreadyInitialized && firstRender)
    {
        _isAlreadyInitialized = true;

        await Redraw(_cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This overrides the method of the base class from the library. The base class implementation is as follows..

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    await this.Initialize();
  else
    await this.Update();
}
```

It is this call to `Initialize` which is calling another method..

```
private static object ToChartDataSet<T>(ChartData<T> data)
{
  return (object) new
  {
    Labels = data.Labels,
    Datasets = ((IEnumerable<object>) data.Datasets).ToList<object>()
  };
}
```

..and it's here where the data is null.

For some reason using await/async in the `Redraw` method results in the base class calling `Initialize` => `ToChartDataSet` before the call to `DataProvider.Get` is complete. When using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` then `Initialize` is not called until the `DataProvider.Get` has completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: "I believe that it's because the Redraw is trying to run before the data task is finished" - no, the await must have completed to get to the redraw call, so that shouldn't be the cause. This could perhaps be a subtle sync-context thing; is there a stack trace?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll add the trace

Comment: The error is triggered by passing `null` as an argument to `Chart.Redraw`. It looks like `data.Labels` returns `null`. Can you reproduce this or is this a random error? In debug mode check the value of `data.Label`. If it's `null`, you have to find the reason, why the `Label` property is not set to a value. This has nothing to do with async/await.

Comment: `Label` is not `null` when I debug it - it's not random either, it happens every time. @BionicCode

Comment: Please check the value of `data.DataSet`.

Comment: Both `data.Label` and `data.DataSet` are not null.

Comment: Have you tried to call `base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender)` from inside your override _before_  you continue to execute your custom code?

Comment: I can give it a try ;)

Comment: It didn't work to call the base first - firstly because what I thought was the base class was not the base class but another class that inherited from the same base class. In the end it was not the `Chart.Redraw` method that was triggering the error. It was a call to `Initialize` in a different `BaseChart` class. Providing a default instance of `ChartData` in the index.razor component fixed it.